# Regex Pattern not alow zero

Tags: c#, regex

I have this Pattern it's worked successful:

```
@"^-?(0\.\d*[0-9]|[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)$
```

but I want this pattern not allow zero like this inputs:

```
not allowed inputs:
0.0     //not allowed
00.00   //not allowed


allowed inputs:

0.07    // allowed
0.70    // allowed
and any number decimal
```

Comment: What is the goal of this pattern? If it is just to see if what they entered is a decimal that isn't 0, there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: So what is your question? Did you try something and it did not work?

Comment: yes i want regex pattern to decimal numbers without zero like this 0 or 0.00

Comment: I agree with @Justin. Why not just [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/9zbda557.aspx) the input (maybe even with specifying an [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ew0seb73.aspx)) and see if it equals [Decimal.Zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.decimal.zero.aspx)?

Comment: Just use this, `decimal.TryParse('0.00', out result); result == decimal.Zero ? "Fail" : "Pass"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make the regex fail if it is only "0".

```
@"^-?(?!0*(\.0*)?$)(0\.\d*[0-9]|[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36f0u)

This expression `(?!0*(\.0*)?$)` makes the whole regex fail, if the number consists only of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

**Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).